# No way to customise padding on DropdownButtonFormField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the DropdownButtonFormField. It seems to have no way to customise the padding. With the TextFormField, if I set dense to true, I can customise the padding, etc. to make it the size I want. I set dense to true on the DropdownButtonFormField and nothing happens.

See screenshot below

[image]

Edit:

I can control the height with a container

[image]

but when there is an error, it shrinks in an extremely weird way, likely because the container wraps the whole dropdown button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try my code pasted below. I think we can wrap it with container to customize the padding too. Please ignore the functionality onpress property.

```
Tooltip(
      message: "Maker dropdown",
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).hoverColor,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: ButtonTheme(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                alignedDropdown: true,
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<Makers>(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  dropdownColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon:  FaIcon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.screwdriverWrench,
                        color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                      enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
                      fillColor: Colors.transparent),
                  value: _myMaker,
                  iconSize: 15.0,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
                  elevation: 8,
                  hint: AutoSizeText("Select Maker",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3),
                  onChanged: (Makers? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      _myMaker = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                  validator: (value) => Validator.validateMakers(
                    myMaker: _myMaker,
                  ),
                  items: items = _makersList
                      .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<Makers>(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    value: item,
                    child: Text(item!.name),
                  ))
                      .toList(),
                ))),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: When I wrap with a container and use it with an errorText (like in a form). It does not work well.

Comment: I have edited my answer and attached the image for your reference.

Comment: my bad. perhaps i didnt explain it well enough. please see the updated question describing how the issue persists.

Comment: understood refer below answer

Answer (score 0):

In the input decoration property please add below codes and check. hope it works. counter text do the trick. also see the image below

filled: true,
counterText: "",
contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0, horizontal: 20.0),

[image]